# How to export JQ grid contents to Powerpoint file?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, powerpoint-2010

HI I'm new to MVC my project requires an option to Export a Jqgrid contents to power point slide when the export button is pressed.

I Couldn't find any solution anywhere. Please help me.

This is the code to display the grid.

I have only included the view part:

```
                    <div class="col-md-8" style="text-align:right;padding-right:40px;">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="btnExportppt"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Export Powerpoint</button>
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;">
            <label id="lblMsg"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-right:3em;">
        @(Html.Grid("grdReports")

                     .AddColumn(new Column("DealID").SetLabel("DealID").AddClass("nowrap").SetWidth(83))
                     .AddColumn(new Column("ClientName").SetLabel("Client Name").AddClass("nowrap"))
                     .AddColumn(new Column("OppName").SetLabel("Opportunity Name").AddClass("nowrap").SetWidth(172))
                     .AddColumn(new Column("DealStatusID").SetLabel("Deal Status").AddClass("nowrap"))
                     .AddColumn(new Column("DealClosureQuarter").SetLabel("Deal Closure Quarter ").AddClass("nowrap").SetWidth(192))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("SolutionChampion").SetLabel("Soln. Champions / Account POC").AddClass("nowrap").SetWidth(158))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("RegionName").SetLabel("Region/City").AddClass("nowrap"))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("ScopeSummary").SetLabel("Opportunity Scope").AddClass("nowrap").SetWidth(208))//new
                      .AddColumn(new Column("CRMId").SetLabel("CRM Id").AddClass("nowrap"))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("TowersInPlayID").SetLabel("Towers").AddClass("nowrap"))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("Probability").SetLabel("Win Probability").AddClass("nowrap"))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("TCV").SetLabel("Total TCV($ million)").AddClass("nowrap").SetWidth(174))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("TotalScore").SetLabel("Qualification Score").AddClass("nowrap").SetWidth(174))//new
                      .AddColumn(new Column("Contractduration").SetLabel("Contract Length (Months/Years)").AddClass("nowrap"))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("DealClosureMonth").SetLabel("Month (Won/Lost)").AddClass("nowrap").SetWidth(194))//new
                      .AddColumn(new Column("VerticalID").SetLabel("Vertical").AddClass("nowrap"))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("GeographyID").SetLabel("Geography").AddClass("nowrap"))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("Executive").SetLabel("Executive Sponsor").AddClass("nowrap").SetWidth(178))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("AMCPName").SetLabel("CP / AM").AddClass("nowrap"))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("MSIFlag").SetLabel("MSI Pursue Flag (Y/N)").AddClass("nowrap").SetWidth(215))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("MSIScope").SetLabel("MSI Scope").AddClass("nowrap").SetWidth(178))//new
                      .AddColumn(new Column("NextSteps").SetLabel("Key Dates & Next steps").AddClass("nowrap").SetWidth(227))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("FTEEstimate").SetLabel("FTEs-Transition & Steady State").AddClass("nowrap").SetWidth(309))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("Downselectstatus").SetLabel("Downselected").AddClass("nowrap"))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("ThirdPartyID").SetLabel("Third Party Advisor").AddClass("nowrap").SetWidth(219))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("IncumbencyID").SetLabel("Are we Incumbent").AddClass("nowrap").SetWidth(190))
                      .AddColumn(new Column("Competitors").SetLabel("Competition").AddClass("nowrap"))

                .SetDataType(MvcJqGrid.Enums.DataType.Local)
                .SetDataType(MvcJqGrid.Enums.DataType.Local)
                .SetLoadOnce(true)
                .SetScroll(true)
                //.SetPager("pager")
                .SetScrollRows(true)
                .SetAutoWidth(true)
                .SetHeight(250)
                .SetHiddenGrid(true)
                 .SetRowNum(1000000000)
                .SetShrinkToFit(false)

        .OnSelectRow("onSelectGrid(rowid,status)")

        )
        <div id="pager"></div>
```

Comment: What does "Export a Jqgrid contents to power point slide" mean to you?  What do you want to end up with in PPT?  A table, I'd guess?

Comment: yes i nee to get the content s of my table to ppt

Comment: yes i need to end up with a table in the ppt file

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd add a table and populate it in VBA; you'll need to supply your own parameters (number of rows/columns) and populate the data yourself:

```
Sub AddTable()
' Adds a 3x4 table to slide 1 of the current presentation
' and populates it with data

    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oTbl As Table
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
        ' add table, accept default top/left/height/width
        Set oTbl = .Shapes.AddTable(4, 3).Table

        With oTbl
            For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For lCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    .Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
                    "Row " & CStr(lRow) & "/" & "Col " & CStr(lCol)
                Next
            Next
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: No idea.  Translation is left as an exercise for the reader.  Try it, post what you end up with if you have problems ... my C# is like my Spanish.  Can't speak or write it, but can often read it passably well.  And surely someone else who's more fluent will be able to help.